# How to iterate through pdf pages for inserting page number in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf, jspdf

What I m trying to achieve is to get the saved pdf from asset folder in angular 7 and insert page number through jsPDF in each page. I am stuck just after getting the pdf like this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/pdf');

this.http.get('/assets/pdf/myTest.pdf', { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I am able to get the pdf but unable to loop through each page for inserting page number using `jsPDF` in `angular 7`. My Pdf do not have page number in it. Inserting page number through jsPdf can be achieved like this:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.page=1; // use this as a counter.

function footer(){ 
   doc.text(150,285, 'page ' + doc.page); //print number bottom right
   doc.page ++;
};

// and call footer() after each doc.addPage()
```

Sample pdf can be [this](https://ilearn.marist.edu/access/lessonbuilder/item/172134/group/e0d1b466-ea21-433b-8926-c41f19455217/Course%20Materials/SamplePDF.pdf). How can I insert page number in the saved pdf? any solution are highly appreciated.

Comment: This code looks quite fine. Are you sure (150,285) is not off the page or anything?

Comment: I am unable to loop through the pdf pages after which page number can be inserted

Comment: @Iswar ...yes, that is your original question, I saw it. What about my question?